# Unable to import module 'api/candidate': Error at Function.Module._resolveFilename

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless-framework

I am creating Serverless application using Lamda functions in nodejs,Dynmodb and Serverless framwork .I have created Lamda function 
to get data from Dynmodb table but I am getting this error when I am trying to fetch data through end point.

**Lamda Function index.js :**

```
'use strict';
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(); 

exports.list = function(event, context, callback){
    var params = {
        TableName : process.env.TABLE_NAME
    };
    documentClient.scan(params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            callback(err);
        }else{
            callback(null, data.Items);
        }
    });
}
```

**error in  CloudWatchLog Groups/aws/lambda/my-service-dev-listCandidates:**

```
Unable to import module 'api/candidate': Error
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

**While fetching data from Endpoint I am getting this:**

{"message": "Internal server error"}

Answer (score 1):

You might have other things that are wrong, but for sure you have wrong syntax in the require:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
```

should be:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

Comment: After changing I am still getting this error in my cloudwatch : module initialization error: ReferenceError
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:100:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)

Comment: Solved ..actually, I was not returning any state that is it was giving me an error